# Wordpress menu disappears when using a Twitter bootstrap plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

The page in question is http://dev.gapsummit.com/?page_id=2

With no Bootstrap plugin enabled, you can see the menu items like so
[image: Screenshot of working menu bar]

With either of these BootStrap plugins enabled, the menu bar is [hidden](http://dev.gapsummit.com/?page_id=2).

- [Easy Bootstrap shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-bootstrap-shortcodes/)
- [Wordpress Twitter Bootstrap CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/)

The menu items are still present in the source file, they are just hidden. If anyone can help me unhide them (point out what css is hiding the element), I would be most grateful!

Answer (score 1):

It is the class .dropdown-menu that bootstrap is picking up. Over-ride the rules for the menu with !important in your own css and your menu will appear.

```
.dropdown-menu{
  display:block !important;
   //other style rules with !important
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that :) I added it in and can now see the menu, but it still doesn't show up in one horizontal line. http://dev.gapsummit.com/?page_id=2

Comment: you need to override the other style rules check what bootstrap has applied to the element in your dev tools.  P.S if its only supposed to become a drop down on a small screen size (responive) then either use a media query to adjust your style rules based on screen size or remove the dropdown menu class and apply it with js on resize